# Error in Java: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error near ;

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = " insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (:name,SRID=4326;POINT(:x :y))", nativeQuery = true)   
@Transactional
void addSPCTY(@Param("name") String ten,@Param("x") String x,@Param("y") String y);
```

It error when I run . I can't Insert data
Please Help me. Tks all.

Comment: You are creating 3 questions with same thing

Answer (score 0):

Remove the  ";" character of your query, it looks like a syntax error of your query.

Maybe something like this can work :

```
insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (:name,POINT(:x :y))
```

2 Params definition and 2 args.